# Constructor asp.net class

Tags: c#, asp.net, class

```
    public class Leden
    {
        public Leden() //Leden Contructor
        {
        }

        // Methods

        public int Lidnummer {get; set;}
        public string Naam {get; set;}
        public string AchterNaam {get; set;}
        public bool Geslacht {get; set;}
        public string Leeftijd {get; set;}
        public DateTime AanmeldDatum {get; set;}
        public DataTable getLeden(bool filter) {}
        public string Presentje(int Lidnummer) { }

}
```

Here is my class.

As you al can see i have added 2 properties but they both wont work at the points 
getLeden and Presentje it give red lines how can i resolve this ?

Comment: You ask some very different questions. Please only ask one question per post. Helping you with syntax is very different from solving your problem with database entries.

Comment: Remove " } " At the end . And add () in third line "public Leden()".

Comment: it's now different from original question you've posted. please split it into two.

Comment: I will Rephrase 
The first question is solved i changed the things that all of you pointed out.

now its just the question for the date mutation when the button is klicked

Comment: what provider for data access are you using? is that ORM approach?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server (SqlClient)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: Since the question got updated, this answer isn't really valid anymore.

You messed up your `{` and `}`. Additionally, you forgot to put `()` after your ctor declaration.

Your code should look like this:

```
public class Leden
{
    public Leden() //Leden Contructor <-- here you were missing '()'
    {
        // do stuff in your constructor...
    }

    // Metodes <-- these are commonly called properties

    public int Lidnummer {get; set;}
    public string Naam {get; set;}
    public string AchterNaam {get; set;}
    public bool Geslacht {get; set;}
    public string Leeftijd {get; set;}
    public Datetime AanmeldDatum {get; set;}
} // <-- you had one '}' too many at this point
```

Comment: you pointed out the problem for the contructor part thats fixed thanks now its just the matter for the mutation part

Comment: It's generally better to ask new question in new posts and not update your question as that invalidates all answers up to that point. To help you with your database problem, we'd need to know a bit more about your environment. Just open a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

You should put brackets after constructor method name:

```
public Leden() //Leden Contructor
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Leden
{
        public Leden() //Leden Contructor
        {
        }

    // Metodes
    public void ChangeAanmeldDatum()
    {
        AanmeldDatum = DateTime.Now;
    }

    public int Lidnummer {get; set;}
    public string Naam {get; set;}
    public string AchterNaam {get; set;}
    public bool Geslacht {get; set;}
    public string Leeftijd {get; set;}
    public DateTime AanmeldDatum {get; set;}
}
```